# iOS ordering behaviors in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, cgrectmake

In the `viewDidLoad`, I have an initial setup like this -

```
// Output all the appropriate text to UITextLabel depending on the state of the app
[self presentData];

// Button sizing 
UIelement.frame=CGRectMake(blah blah blah);
```

Why is it that when I do it in the previous order, I get the text outputted without the size adjusting until present data is called again by another function while when I type the code in the order of

```
UIelement.frame=CGRectMake(blah blah blah);
[self presentData];
```

it will size it appropriately to start. 
I understand that the order is important but what I want to know is why? How would I go about finding out why something like this happens the next time I have a problem like this? my guess is that presenting the data, changing the uilabel, updates the view but for some reason cgrectmake does not update the view but just changes the value of the uilabel's frame in the model. Am I correct? How would I go about finding the answer to a question like this without having to ask the online community next time?

Comment: You refer to `UITextLabel`. I assume you meant `UILabel`. Later you refer to `UIelement`, but the comment talks about "button sizing". Precisely what sort of controls are we talking about?

Comment: Also, how were these controls added? Programmatically or via IB? Show us more code...

Comment: The controls were added through interface builder, linked up to @properties and programmatically. yeah I did mean uilabel.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possibilities:

1. You are apparently using [auto layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html). With auto layout, the process of setting the `text` property of a label will result in the constraints being reapplied for the view. When you manually set a `frame`, that only stays in effect until the auto layout constraints are reapplied (e.g. you update a `UILabel` again or you call `layoutIfNeeded`), at which point the `frame` is recalculated/adjusted. Generally in auto layout, one wouldn't adjust a frame manually.
2. Perhaps `presentData` is calling `sizeToFit`, or something like that? This will obviously change the `frame`, too.

Comment: I am not using auto layout. I unchecked it because it would not allow me to change the size of anything without it unchecked.

Comment: Hmm. Auto-layout is the only thing that I know of that would explain this behavior. Note, even if the storyboard has auto layout turned off, if you have any code that is programmatically adding any constraints, that that affect the behavior. If that's still not it, I'd suggest creating a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem. If we can't reproduce it, it's hard to help.

Comment: present data is calling sizetofit. I didn't know how that worked and I saw an example online so i just used it without looking into it. Should I be using it outside present data since i'm calling presentdata alot? (alot of times I just see a function online and just try it out to see if it works without looking at how or why it works)
edit"probably shouldn't do that lol"

Comment: It seems quite plausible for `presentData` to call `sizeToFit` when it's updating the text in the labels. But this obviously answers your question about the behavior you've seen. If you manually override the frames set by `sizeToFit`, those frames won't be readjusted until you call your `presentData` again...